# Image1. Picture doesn't get cleared when i run the below code

Tags: excel, vba

This code is to save employee data as well his photo to a specific folder.

Problem:
Employee A whose emp id is A1 has photo and on running this code all his basic details gets saved in a excel sheet and the photo gets saved in the specific folder with Name "A1".

Now if i add a new employee B whose Emp id A2 but it does not have photo and on running this code all his basic details gets saved in excel but **Employee A's photo also gets saved with name "A2"**. Please help me write a code to clear the image each time so that old photo does not get saved in new employee id.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click() 'save employee master button
    lastrow = Sheets("Employee Database").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(vbNullString)
    
    For Z = 2 To lastrow
        On Error Resume Next
        
        If Sheets("Employee Master").Range("c5").Value = Sheets("Employee Database").Cells(Z, 1).Value Then
            MsgBox ("Please check the entry or Click on Update")
            Exit Sub
        Else:
        
        End If
    Next
        
    On Error Resume Next
    
    Dim i As String
     
    i = Range("c5").Text
      
    If Sheets("Employee Master").Range("c7").Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please Add Employee Name", vbOKCancel
    
        If vbOK Then Exit Sub
    Else:
        Call saveemployeedata
        
        FileCopy FPATH, "E:\SATYA\BANK\1-SALARY SHEET\2-EMPLOYEE ID\EMP PHOTO\" & i & ".JPG"
    
        MsgBox "Employee Data Saved Sucessfully", vbInformation
        
        If Image1.Picture Is Nothing Then
            Exit Sub
        Else:
            Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(vbNullString)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What is `FPATH`?  Is it the file path of the employee's photo?

Comment: Please, could you indent your code - and remove the `:` after the `Else`. Plus, remove the `On Error Resume Next` - statements.

Comment: Using `On Error Resume Next` in a not working code, only does not let you seeing where the problem is...